# How to get the nested items from the Content Tree in Sitecore and build a sitemap?

Tags: c#, loops, razor, sitecore, sitemap

I wrote a `foreach` loop, but it only displays the 1st level pages. I want to receive all the nested pages from the Content Tree. For example, *Home > Company > About the company > Line of business ...*

I want to display all the above-nested pages.

My code:

```
if (child.HasChildren)
    {
      <ul class="sitemap__section-links--subnav">
        @foreach (Item cChild in child.Children)
        {
         if (cChild.Fields[Templates.Data.Folders.BaseTemplates.Fields.BaseNavigation.Fields.IncludeInSitemap] != null && cChild.Fields[Templates.Data.Folders.BaseTemplates.Fields.BaseNavigation.Fields.IncludeInSitemap].Value == "1")
          {
           <li><a class="sitemap__section-link--subnav" href="@LinkManager.GetItemUrl(@cChild, new UrlOptions(){AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true})">@CAASCOnt.BusinessLayer.Extensions.ItemExtensions.GetPageTitle(cChild)</a></li>
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There are a few ways to do this, but first to clarify: Do you want to display them all as a flat list, or do you want to preserve their hierarchy as you output them to your sitemap?

Also, as a side note, I notice that you are referencing some generated IDs for what appears to be some sort of framework of templates. You probably already have a navigation menu or sitemap control if you have this sort of framework and it likely has the logic you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, Jay for your reply. 
1. Yes I want to display them all as a flat list
2. I don't think there is any framework used for sitemap, but I can still check, where can I see if any framework is installed for sitemap? 
Also, as I mentioned I use Sitecore.

Comment: Move the foreach into a helper, and pass the item to it as well (cChild). Then, after the <li> in that helper call the helper once more so you have a way to keep drilling down. You'll want to move the HasChildren into that helper as well.

Comment: @aneo: Almost any Sitecore implementation has some form of "base framework" of components that are put in there by the implementation team. Without knowing what framework you are using, there is no way to provide guidance as to where to find the things.

You might want to search in your solution for something like "sitemap" and see if a template or View pops up. You might also have a "menu" or "navigation" control that does something similar.